# How to disable buttons in button-group (Bootstrap)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I have a button-group like the one on the picture:

[image]

and the code like this:

```
<span class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <span class="btn btn-default active">
    <input type="radio" value="false"><label >No</label>
  </span>
  <span class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" value="true"><label >Yes</label>
  </span>
</span>
```

**How do I disable this control completely?** When I added bootstrap class `.disabled` and/or attribute `disabled` to any or all of these elements I still could click on the buttons and they were affected even though bootstrap was showing the crossed circle icon.

I found [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15696) a workaround that stops events propagation, however it works only to prevent adding `active` class to the buttons but not `focus`.

```
$('.btn-group .btn.disabled').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23518378/disable-twitter-bootstrap-button-group

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331261/disable-radio-button-in-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.btn-group .btn.disabled').click(function(event) {
     return false;
});
```